# Peewee timeout on mysql connection

Tags: peewee

I have a flask application with Peewee as ORM.
All good but i want to manage the case where the database is down.

Is it possible to place a timeout on connection ? how do you manage the fact that the database is down with peewee ?

I tried to manage an exeption with connect but without result.

Answer (score 1):

If the database is down can your application reliably function? It might be best to register an error handler -- this is a callback that accepts the exception -- and, depending on the error you might display to the user a message that the database is down.

Flask register error handler doc: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/errorhandling/#registering

You can check that the exception corresponds to a connection error to the database and take proper action in the callback, such as rendering a special page.